# global watch of object instance

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to watch object's property values. Is it possible to have some kind of a global watch, the one that doesn't depend on visibility scope

for example one method is somewhere in a callstack, it receives an object does something to it, and then control flow goes to undebuggable zone where I can't step through code, and then after some time control flow comes back to the place where I can step through code, but I don't know now where is my object that was given to someMethod (but I am sure that object is alive and is stored in a filed of an instance of a class). Are there something like an address (like address in memory) using which I could find watch object in Expressions panel in Eclipse?

call stack:

```
someMethod(Object o)
<undebuggable zone>
someOtherMethod
```

What i want is to watch object o when I am in someOtherMethod

Answer (score 1):

I think you need "public static" entity.

You can create test public class with public static fields. Set your object into one of its field and you can see this objects value everywhere.

Comment: Heh, I have a lot of such objects so that would be difficult, but anyway thank you for an idea

Comment: Why it should be difficult? Only one more object. In every IDE you can explicit set the name of class or object you want to see in debug console.

Comment: I would have to add one more class, that is not a problem, but how can I easily add and remove necessary objects? For example I need to commit by changes to svn, so first I have remember somehow all positions where I add assignment to a global class field, then delete them, and after commit I would have to restore this helper code

Comment: Try to use IoC container. For example you can add one more spring configuration file where you will set all necessary objects. If you need to turn debug mode off just exclude this file from project.